# Authentication Error: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405

Tags: angular

I want to implement authentication. Actually, my project is being built in Angular 2 Beta, but I'm using [this](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-authentication-sample) authentication sample for testing purposes. I have own API, and just added its url to this sample project. It didn't work) It shows this error:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 405 (Method Not Allowed)
Fetch API cannot load http://blah-blah-blah. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
```

Here is the login method:

```
login(event, phone, password) {
event.preventDefault();
window.fetch('http://blah-blah-blah', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    phone, password
  })
})
.then(status)
.then(json)
.then((response:any) => {
  localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.id_token);
  this.router.parent.navigateByUrl('/home');
})
.catch((error) => {
  alert(error.message);
  console.log(error.message);
});
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to make a cross domain AJAX call. For this to work your remote server API must support [`CORS`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS). The pre-flight request is a special request that the browser sends using the OPTIONS verb prior to making the actual POST request:

```
OPTIONS http://blah-blah-blah
```

The server must respond with a normal 200 status code and include the proper CORS headers indicating which domains are allowed to make requests to it. Only after that the actual POST request will be sent.

The problem with your API is that the endpoint returned 405 Not Allowed status code to this `OPTIONS` request. So you will need to fix your API so that it supports the `OPTIONS` verb.

Comment: I think you missed the point of my answer. The problem is not in your Angular application. It is on the server side API that you are trying to call. That's where you should fix the problem and enable CORS, So basically you should enable CORS for the `http://api.paydacard.kz/identity/login` endpoint. In your question you mentioned that this is your own API so it should not be a problem updating it.

Comment: I got it) But I can't configure API, I have no access to it.

Comment: Oh, then you have a problem. If you can't change the code of this API you would need to setup another API that is hosted on the same domain as your angular app and which will serve as a bridge between your domain and the remote domain. So basically you will send the AJAX request from your angular app to this local API like `/myapi` and it will take care of delegating the call by making a server side request to the remote API.

Comment: The code you are showing is angular and javascript. No matter what you do on the client you will not be able to circumvent the same origin policy restriction that's built into the browsers and which forbids you from making cross domain AJAX calls. I really recommend you reading a little bit about CORS in order to better understand how this works and how to enable it on the server.

Comment: Here's an article which makes a good overview: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: This link could also show you how it works: http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/