# POST Angular 2 application/json

Tags: json, angular, api, post, postman

I am currently developing and app with Angular 2, but am hitting some problems when using the POST data to the API.

Below is how I set the *Headers* and *Options* in Angular.

```
const object = {
    AccessToken: accessToken,
    Item: {
        Id: role.Id,
        Name: role.Name,
        AuthorizedThreshold: role.AuthorizedThreshold
    }
};
const url = this.serverUrl + '/api/Role/Update';
const myHeaders = new Headers(); 
myHeaders.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
myHeaders.set('Accept', 'application/json'); 
const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: myHeaders });

return this.http.post(url, object, options).map((res: Response) => res.json());
```

Whenever I try to make a POST a error 405 occurs.

[image]

Then this is that then, when I mock the call with *Postman*, setting the header and content type to 'application/json', it works using the same payload.

Below please find the *Postman* results.

[image]

The below was set in the WebConfig API

```
<httpProtocol>
  <customHeaders>
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
    <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE,OPTIONS" />
 </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

Anyone has encountered this issue?

Thanks,

Comment: Will you please post the image of postman with all data in it ?

Comment: Maybe the API you posting to doesn't allow POST from you?

Comment: Did you try google? Plenty of questions and answers out there, i.e CORS seems to be your issue :)

Comment: updated the question, and uploaded the Postman result. It is accepting POST from Postman.

Comment: yes, I did try to google, else I wouldn't have asked here, but I am not finding the exact issue, and I am kinda lost..

Comment: You need to set the backend to accept CORS requests.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34461724/authentication-error-response-for-preflight-has-invalid-http-status-code-405

Comment: The thing is that using JQuery Ajax calls and Postman works.. already setup the Backend API with    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Content-Type" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>

Comment: Postman works differently from your api. I don't know whatever backend you are using, so I cannot say what is correct, but this is a backend issue, not really angular.

Comment: I am using C# Web API as a backend, but what I am finding strange is that I did a quick JQuery POST and it worked fine.